# Push query object to view controller

Tags: xcode, object, uiviewcontroller, action

I have a query that grabs 10 objects, and I am trying to have an action that shows you a window with more information on the object selected, I am just new to Xcode and cannot figure out how to push the information to the new view controller. Here is the code I have that creates the query.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Arcade"];
CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
PFGeoPoint *userLocation =
[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                       longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
query.limit = 10;
[query whereKey:kPAWParseLocationKey nearGeoPoint:userLocation withinMiles:kPAWWallPostMaximumSearchDistance];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        int i = 0;
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            if (i >= [self.EventTitles count]) break;//to make sure we only write up to the max number of UILabels available in EventTitles
            [(UILabel *)self.EventTitles[i] setText:[object objectForKey:@"name"]];//I assume the "objectId" property of object is an NSString!
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

and this is the action to push to the new view controller:

```
-(IBAction)DetailEvent1:(id)sender{

TableDetailViewController  *objDetail = [[TableDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:objDetail];
objDetail.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height - 0.0f);
[self.view addSubview:objDetail.view];
```

}

If someone could help me write the one line of code that needs to be added to the DetailEvent1 action so that the chosen object is pushed I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
TableDetailViewController  *objDetail = 
    [[TableDetailViewController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
objDetail.query = self.query
```

In other words, this is the moment you are creating the next view controller. The two view controllers are now in contact (`self` and `objDetail`). So this is the moment to pass data across from the one to the other.

Of course, there is no `TableDetailViewController` property `query`. Not yet! But you're going to make one, don't you see - so that you can make this exact move.

Oh, and perhaps there is no `query` property in `self` either. But you will need one, because you need a way to hold on to the `query` that you got in that first method so that it is still available to you in the second method. The way to share data between methods of the same object is very often thru a property.

See also this example [from my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_visibility_by_instantiation):

```
- (void)showItemsForRow: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
    // create subtable of tracks and go there
    TrackViewController *t =
        [[TrackViewController alloc] initWithMediaItemCollection:
            (self.albums)[indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:t animated:YES];
}
```

In that example, I've gone even further: I've actually given TrackViewController a designated initializer so that I can create it and hand it the data all in one line.

Comment: That all makes sense, however you are correct about query not being declared in either controller.. How and where do I need to declare the query?

Comment: Well, it might be good to learn Objective-C and how objects and classes work. Things like [what a property is](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_properties_2) and how to declare it... And why...